# Eclipse Ant Script Complie Package Doesnt exist

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am compiling a project in Eclipse. I have following ant script which complies a java project I am using import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpc;

I have added xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar to a folder named jar and to build path as well as in ant as below. I am getting error `"package org.apache.xmlrpc does not exist   [javac] import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpc;` Am I missing something ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="buildFiles" default="compile">

    <path id="compileClasspath">
                <fileset dir="jar"/>
    </path>

     <target name="compile" description="compile the source " >
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="build"/>
        <classpath refid="compileClasspath"/>
     </target>

</project>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The jar itself must be in the classpath. Not the directory containing the jar:

```
<path id="compileClasspath">
    <fileset dir="jar">
        <include name="xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Please post the tree of your directories and files (where is the build.xml file, where is the sources directory, the build directory, the jar directory, and the jar file)

Answer (score 0):

The Classpath needs to be defined inside the javac task.

```
<javac srcdir="." destdir="/>
    <classpath refid="compileClasspath"/>
```

Should be:

```
<javac srcdir="." destdir="build">
    <classpath refid="compileClasspath"/>
</javac>
```

Hope that helps.